# Not redirected to logout page using Bluemix nodejs with BlueId authentication

Tags: node.js, express, ibm-cloud

The starting point of my Bluemix application is app.js where the user is logged into the application and then later the static middleware is loaded. Unauthorized blueId users DO get redirected to the html logout page before the static middleware is loaded.  The problem is that after the static middleware is loaded, invoking https with '/logout' does run this and  the console log message gets displayed but the application IS NOT redirected to the logout.html page.

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    console.log("in logout");
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy(function(err) {
      res.send(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../logout.html'), 'utf8');
   });   
});
```

...

```
app.use('/', ensureAuthenticated, express.static(__dirname + '/midwear'));

app.use(ensureAuthenticated, function root(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/midwear/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean with "when invoked from within another module in the nodejs application"?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.  The BlueId logout url was in another domain and I needed to add a res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); before sending the file and also I needed to display the response when I got it via document.write(response);